# Remove column names from formulae (Convert into regular cell coordinates without sheet names)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, label

I have a defined table of several rows and columns containing data and formulae. Some of the columns' cells' formulae are:

```
=[@[Weight]]*1000
```

Where 'Weight' is the name of a column heading.

I want to change `=[@[Weight]]*1000` into something like `=C3*1000`.

I've read converting to range does the trick (in the tools section of the Design tab menu). I've tried this however, it changes my formula to the following:

```
='Sheet3'!$C3*1000
```

So, is there a way to change `=[@[Weight]]*1000` to `=C3*1000` for all cells of this format?

...(**Not** `'Sheet3'!$C3*1000`, as the cell I'm editing is already in Sheet 3, so there shouldn't be a reason to reference Sheet 3)

Any help/advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When 'Converting to Range' I lose the benefit of having a defined table...So, can I do the above without converting to range? - I'm assuming after converting to range you can't reverse the conversion to keep the table but remove the structured labels from the formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what reason you would actually want to do this, but follow these steps:

- First convert to range as described,
- Then press `CTRL` +`A`, `CTRH` + `H`,
- In the find box put `'Sheet3'!`
- In the replace box put `''`

This will remove all reference to sheet 3,

Comment: Thank you for your response. Two things: If I 'convert do range', wouldn't I loose the benefits of having a 'defined table'? Secondly, I tried to edit your answer, as with your current values it didn't work as you say. shouldn't the find box be `'Sheet3'!$` and the replace box be empty?

Comment: the replace box should be empty, I was trying to show that with '', but the $ is attached to the Cell ref not the sheet name. if you don't want to change the table, just re-write your formula to look to cell C3 instead, and drag down etc.

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is as follows: Having Sheet 3 in every formula is distracting. `=C3*1000` is much cleaner than `='Sheet3'!$C3*1000`.

Comment: Having the formula with a structured label like `=[@[Weight]]*1000` is confusing when trying to locate and difficult to edit. Also, I'm unable to move the highlighted [@[Weight]] whereas when it's formatted as `=C3*1000` I can easily move (with my cursor by clicking and dragging) C3 to D3 or C1 or F5 etc.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I think so far, in order to keep the defined table, we can only do it as you mentioned in your last comment ("just re-write your formula to look to cell C3 instead, and drag down etc") which is pretty manual (not automatic)...- I'm assuming after converting to range you can't reverse the conversion to keep the table but remove the structured labels from the formulae. I've added a comment to my question to reflect this.

Comment: @questioner56 you can reverse the range back to a table, as long as the table is not being refreshed via an outside source, i.e sql, odbc or something, select the whole table and press Ctrl + T

Comment: @questioner56 and welcome to Super User by the way !

Comment: Thank you @PeterH! Kind of you to say that. And thank you for pointing out the `Ctrl + T`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn Structured References (Table Formulas) Off:

1. Click File > Options in Excel.
2. Click the Formulas option on the left side menu.
3. In the Working with Formulas section, uncheck the box that says “Use table names in formulas”.
4. Press OK.

Reference [How to Turn OFF Structured References in Excel Table Formulas - From Excel Campus](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/turn-off-structured-references-table-formulas/):